# How to show message if there are duplicated values in DB using ajax in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, duplicates, asp.net-ajax

I have a form where I'm adding some values in DB using ajax and I've made all the logik to avoit adding if there is some duplicated value, but I want to show a simple message below "id="txtTitle" input, that "such number already exists". Until now I've tryed to show an alart message, after button click, but it doesn't work. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

this ist my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddNewEvent(Event e)
    {
        try { 
        using(EventsDBEntities db = new EventsDBEntities())
        {
                List<Event> evts = db.Events.Where(x => x.Title == e.Title).ToList();
                
                if(evts.Count > 0)
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "<script>alert('This order number already exists, please check it and try again');</script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Events.Add(e);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            
        }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {

        }
        
        return new JsonResult { Data = e,  JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

my MVC View:

```
<div class="modal modal-dialog-centered" id="AddEventCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add new Event:</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="width:auto">

            <div id="dialog-edit" style="width:auto"></div>

            <div id="AddEvent">

                <table style="width:500px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select id="colorChoose">
                                <option value="white">
                                    ---choose---
                                </option>
                                <option value="green">
                                    Maintenance(46535..., 4683...)
                                </option>
                                <option value="yellow">
                                    Field repair(46303..., 4681...)
                                </option>
                                <option value="grey">
                                    Warranty(967..., 968...)
                                </option>
                            </select>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:250px;">
                            <label>Order number :</label><br />
                            <input maxlength="15" style="width:200px;" type="text" id="txtTitle" />
                            // here must be message if Duplicate<input id="ifDuplicate" />
                        </td>

                        <td style="width:250px;">
                            <label>Event Title :</label><br />
                            <input maxlength="20" style="width:200px;" type="text" id="txtDesc" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <br />
                            <label>Full event description:</label>
                            <br />
                            <textarea maxlength="500" style="height:100px;width:500px;resize:none;" id="txtFullDesc"></textarea>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:250px;padding-right:7em;">
                            <label>Address :</label><br />
                            <textarea maxlength="100" style="height:100px;width:200px;resize:none;" id="txtAddress"></textarea>
                        </td>

                        <td style="width:250px;">
                            <label>Contact peson on site :</label><br />
                            <textarea maxlength="100" style="height:100px;width:200px;resize:none;" id="txtContact"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:200px;">
                            <br />
                            <label>Location title :</label>
                            <br />
                            <input maxlength="15" style="width:200px;" type="text" id="txtLoc" />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <input style="width:200px;" type="hidden" id="colorAdd" />
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="return Add();" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Add new event</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
// This is for Add new Data
function Add() {
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/AddNewEvent",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            Title: $('#txtTitle').val(),
            Description: $('#txtDesc').val(),
            Location: $('#txtLoc').val(),
            color: $('#colorAdd').val(),
            fullDescription: $('#txtFullDesc').val(),
            Address: $('#txtAddress').val(),
            Contact: $('#txtContact').val()
        },
        success: function () {
            
            $('#UpdatePanel').load(loadData());
            var res = "";
            $('#txtTitle').val(res),
                $('#txtDesc').val(res),
                $('#txtLoc').val(res),
                $('#colorAdd').val(res),
                $('#txtFullDesc').val(res),
                $('#txtAddress').val(res),
                $('#txtContact').val(res)
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed! Please try again.");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: you didn't specify any parameter under your success function. i.e do `success:function (data)` and then do `alert(data)`

Comment: emmm, ok could work, but in my case, I guess, I need an "If" statement to chenck data from controller(if there are some duplicated values), so I have to get it from it, my data from controller is  return new JsonResult { Data = e,  JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet }; So it return only an object... can You show me an exaple what You mean with "success:function (data)"?

Comment: whatever you will return back will come in `data` or any other variable which you specify under `success:function(yourvariable)` and then you can use this variable to perform further operation.

Comment: no, it doesn't work:    success: function (data) {
                if (data.evts > 0) {
                    $('#duplicate').html("duplicate");
                }
                else
                {